# Can't retrieve a value from an object gotten from a Promise

Tags: javascript, object, stripe-payments

I am attempting to use Stripe's `createSource` and for that, I'm using a promise in the client like so:

```
function prepare(name, email, phone){
                stripe.createSource({
                  type: 'oxxo',
                  amount: <?= $price ?>,
                  currency: 'mxn',
                  owner: {
                    name: name,
                    email: email,
                    phone: phone,
                  },
                }).then(function(result) {
                  handle(result);
                }).catch(function(err){
                  console.log("Error!");
                  console.error(err);
                });
            }
```

this calls `handle()` which looks like so:

```
function handle(source){
                console.log(source); // returns the object in img below

                receiverInfo.innerHTML = `<img width="150px" src="/assets/img/oxxo.png"></img><svg id="barcode"></svg>`;

                    JsBarcode("#barcode", source.oxxo.number, {
                      text: source.oxxo.number.match(/.{1,4}/g).join ("  "),
                      width: 2,
                      height: 50,
                      fontSize: 15,
                    });
            }
```

However when doing this I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'number' of undefined` despite the fact that I can see the value in the console:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see from your code and screenshot, your variable contains an object like this

```
let source = { source: {

   oxxo: { number: 111 }

}}
```

So you need to access like this

```
source.source.oxxo.number
```